# Display info in second drop down box based on selection of the first from array + javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am the webadmin for my fraternity's website but I am not sure how to tackle this problem. I want two drop down boxes in my form. I want that if the user clicks Alpha (chapter) the second drop down box will display Option 1 and Option 2. But if the user selects Beta (chapter) the second drop down box will display Option 3 and Option 4. I am trying to do this purely in JavaScript. How would I go about achieving this?

```js
var chapter = new Array();
chapter[0] = ["Alpha","one","two","Option 1","three","four"];
chapter[1] = ["Alpha","one","two","Option 2","three","four"];
chapter[2] = ["Beta","one","two","Option 3","three","four"];
chapter[3] = ["Beta","one","two","Option 4","three","four"];
chapter[4] = ["Gamma","one","two","Option 5","three","four"];
chapter[5] = ["Gamma","one","two","Option 6","three","four"];
chapter[6] = ["Delta","one","two","Option 7","three","four"];
chapter[7] = ["Delta","one","two","Option 8","three","four"];
chapter[8] = ["Epsilon","one","two","Option 9","three","four"];
chapter[9] = ["Epsilon","one","two","Option 10","three","four"];
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">Choose one</option>
  <option value="Alpha">Alpha</option>
  <option value="Beta">Beta</option>
  <option value="Gamma">Gamma</option>
  <option value="Delta">Delta</option>
  <option value="Epsilon">Epsilon</option>
</select>

<select>
</select>
```

Comment: you have wrote  *if the user clicks alpha (chapter) the second drop down box will display option 2 or option 3*. But in your array `Alpha` value is related with `"Option 1` and `"Option 2` . Why?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo alpha is option one and two beta is 3 and 4

Comment: what these values `.. "one","two" ..` for,  regarding to filling the second selectbox? Can you show how shoud look the second selectbox if I chose `Beta`?

Comment: If you choose beta in drop box one the then drop box two the only selections available would option 3 and option 4

Comment: "one","two","three","four" is dummy data that is in the database

Answer (score 0):

sorry i took much time . because i couldn't use jquery .

```js
var chapter = new Array();
chapter[0] = ["Alpha","one","two","Option 1","three","four"];
chapter[1] = ["Alpha","one","two","Option 2","three","four"];
chapter[2] = ["Beta","one","two","Option 3","three","four"];
chapter[3] = ["Beta","one","two","Option 4","three","four"];
chapter[4] = ["Gamma","one","two","Option 5","three","four"];
chapter[5] = ["Gamma","one","two","Option 6","three","four"];
chapter[6] = ["Delta","one","two","Option 7","three","four"];
chapter[7] = ["Delta","one","two","Option 8","three","four"];
chapter[8] = ["Epsilon","one","two","Option 9","three","four"];
chapter[9] = ["Epsilon","one","two","Option 10","three","four"];

document.getElementById("sell").addEventListener("change", addActivityItem, false);

function addActivityItem(){
  var sel= document.getElementById("sel");
  sel.innerHTML = '';
  var brr=[];
var temp= document.getElementById("sell").value;
chapter.forEach(function(a){
        if(a[0]==temp)
         brr.push(a[3]);   
})  ;

 
  brr.forEach(function(b){
  var newOption = document.createElement('option');
   sel.appendChild(newOption);
   newOption.text=b;
  });

}
```

```html
<select id="sell">
  <option value="">Choose one</option>
  <option value="Alpha">Alpha</option>
  <option value="Beta">Beta</option>
  <option value="Gamma">Gamma</option>
  <option value="Delta">Delta</option>
  <option value="Epsilon">Epsilon</option>
</select>

<select id="sel">
</select>
```

Comment: this is awesome thank you so much, but, for some reason it throws an error when I try to run it. It works in stack overflow but when I run it  I get (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null(…))

Comment: @RonnelLezama oh that's because i have updated in html also . i updated id of select dropdown . change that

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but I am having the same issue with you gave me as the other person that gave an answer (on line 14 i get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null(…))

Comment: @RonnelLezama add `<select id="sell">` in your html  code please . and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I would see if you can restructure the data to make it easier on yourself.

The first bit of code here takes your existing structure and makes into an object, where the properties are the names of the chapters, and the values are the list of options available.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var chapter = new Array();
  chapter[0] = ["Alpha", "one", "two", "Option 1", "three", "four"];
  chapter[1] = ["Alpha", "one", "two", "Option 2", "three", "four"];
  chapter[2] = ["Beta", "one", "two", "Option 3", "three", "four"];
  chapter[3] = ["Beta", "one", "two", "Option 4", "three", "four"];
  chapter[4] = ["Gamma", "one", "two", "Option 5", "three", "four"];
  chapter[5] = ["Gamma", "one", "two", "Option 6", "three", "four"];
  chapter[6] = ["Delta", "one", "two", "Option 7", "three", "four"];
  chapter[7] = ["Delta", "one", "two", "Option 8", "three", "four"];
  chapter[8] = ["Epsilon", "one", "two", "Option 9", "three", "four"];
  chapter[9] = ["Epsilon", "one", "two", "Option 10", "three", "four"];

  var chapters = chapter.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    if (prev[curr[0]]) {
      prev[curr[0]].push(curr[3]);
    } else {
      prev[curr[0]] = [curr[3]];
    }
    return prev;
  }, {});

  document.getElementById('chapter').onchange = function() {
    var name = this.value;
    var dependentValues = chapters[name];
    document.getElementById('options').options.length = 0;
    document.getElementById('options').innerHTML = dependentValues.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      prev += '<option value="' + curr + '">' + curr + '</option>';
      return prev;
    }, '');
  };

};
```

```html
<select id="chapter">
  <option value="">Choose one</option>
  <option value="Alpha">Alpha</option>
  <option value="Beta">Beta</option>
  <option value="Gamma">Gamma</option>
  <option value="Delta">Delta</option>
  <option value="Epsilon">Epsilon</option>
</select>

<select id="options">
</select>
```

The rest of the code is a simple event handler that creates the options by getting the property based the select chapter name, and adds them to the HTML.

Note that the innerHTML trick used here won't work with old versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but I am having the same issue with you gave me as the other person that gave an answer (on line 14 i get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null(…))

Comment: ... Then that's somewhere else in your code. If you look carefully, there is no `addEventListener` in the code I've posted.

Comment: By the way not that I have you can I ask one more question. Do you think it would be possible to add a function that will push the corresponding info into a text box? I Just thought of that. For example if I choose Alpha and in drop down 2 i choose Option one. then in a text box below it will say  one? im just wondering if thats possible or not

Comment: I figured that way the user wouldnt have to waste time typing the information that already in the array.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but it sounds like a new question :).

Comment: ahaha yea it definitely sounds like a new question. You have me there. im gonna check and see if there is anything on SO that points me in that direction but if you dont mind that would be great too.

Comment: You might be better off with [@Roman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40684316/215552) for something like that, since he's still using your original structure. In his code, `c` is the currently selected record, and you can pull the remaining data by using different indexes (e.g., `c[4]` etc.). My answer is geared toward making the data easier to use for this question's needs.

Comment: yea that makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry i swear im not trying to be annoying lol, this is for my own edification. I see Prev and Curr in the code quite a number of times. and because I am trying to understand how it works I tried changing it to random words (yes pokemon was def one of them lol) and it still worked. This led me to believe that those are variables? What is that (curr and prev) supposed to represent?

Comment: Yeah, they're just arguments to the function. Technically `prev` isn't quite correct, but it's how I learned and habits are hard to break :). Check out [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce); basically `reduce` runs through each item in the array; `prev` is what you add stuff to (and in the first runthrough gets the value passed in after the function), and `curr` is the item from the array you're working with for the current iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following optimized approach:

```js
var chapter = [
 ["Alpha","one","two","Option 1","three","four"],
 ["Alpha","one","two","Option 2","three","four"],
 ["Beta","one","two","Option 3","three","four"],
 ["Beta","one","two","Option 4","three","four"],
 ["Gamma","one","two","Option 5","three","four"],
 ["Gamma","one","two","Option 6","three","four"],
 ["Delta","one","two","Option 7","three","four"],
 ["Delta","one","two","Option 8","three","four"],
 ["Epsilon","one","two","Option 9","three","four"],
 ["Epsilon","one","two","Option 10","three","four"]];

document.getElementById("main-box").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var selectbox = document.getElementById("dependant-box"),
 val = this.value;
   
    selectbox.innerHTML = '';  
    chapter.forEach(function(c){
        if (c[0] === val){
    opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.text = c[3];
    selectbox.appendChild(opt);
 }
    });
});
```

```html
<select id="main-box">
  <option value="">Choose one</option>
  <option value="Alpha">Alpha</option>
  <option value="Beta">Beta</option>
  <option value="Gamma">Gamma</option>
  <option value="Delta">Delta</option>
  <option value="Epsilon">Epsilon</option>
</select>

<select id="dependant-box">
</select>
```